# Error Pushing to Remote Git Repo

Tags: git, atlassian-sourcetree

I am trying to push my changes to a Remote Git Repo and I am receiving the following message:

```
remote: error: unable to create temporary file: No space left on device[K
remote: fatal: failed to write object[K
error: unpack failed: unpack-objects abnormal exit
```

Contrary to the message that there is no space left on the remote server, there is plenty of space remaining.

Any help resolving this problem would be appreciated.

Edit #1:
I tried using the command `git repack remote/origin/master` and `git repack` I am still receiving this error after using these commands.

Edit #2:
After accessing the remote server and using the chmod -R 755 command on the .git file the same error persists.

Edit #3:
Another developer is having the same issue while trying to push to remote server. Are there any server side fixes that could be applied?

Note:This did not happen until I resolved a previous local merge conflict

Comment: possible duplicate of [Git push failed - unpack-objects abnormal exit](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8442695/git-push-failed-unpack-objects-abnormal-exit)

Comment: @Makoto I found that article and it was of no help, if you notice my edit #1: I tried the "fix" which is present at that link.

Comment: Have you looked at the other answers?  There is more than one solution there.

Comment: @Makoto Yes, I have tried to fix the problem by accessing the server and using the `chmod -R 755` command on the .git file. The result is the same error.

Comment: All things considered, permissions aren't going to help you if your disk is full - which is what Git seems to be telling you.  There *is* another solution in the previous answer which mentions that you should look to do some cleanup on the server's disk.

Comment: @Makoto The server has over 400GB of available space.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check to make sure that the server isn't full. You can run the following command on Linux to see size of the filesystem:

```
df -h
```

If you don't have any space left you either have to do some cleanup or add more space. If it's a physical machine you would probably need more hard drive space, or if it's a virtual machine you can add more pretty easily.

After you add more space use [Gparted](http://gparted.org/) to re-size your partition, then, once that's done you can follow this link to re-size the file system:
[Extending partition on linux gparted but not more space in the vm](https://serverfault.com/questions/520103/extending-partition-on-linux-gparted-but-not-more-space-in-the-vm)

Comment: That worked like a charm, the VM storage was increased using GParted but it didn't take. After following the link and using those steps it works like a charm. Thank you!